# How Can i get my direct messages in slack api?

Tags: slack, slack-api

How Can i get my direct messages in slack api ?
i have try these methods **search.messages** etc and this link 
**https://slack.com/api/search.messages** but can not show result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all your private messages:

1. Get the list of direct message channels you are a member of with [conversations.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list) by setting the `types` property to `im`
2. Do a loop over the list of all channel and query each with [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) to get all messages.

Make sure to use an access token authorized by yourself to see all private channels.

Comment: I want to get messages not from channel but from direct messages

Comment: your question says "private messages". please update it to "direct messages" and I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @UMDEVELOPER If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as solution. TY